# OpenCV configuration

Tags: opencv, mex, cmake-gui

I am trying to configure OpenCV using CMake-gui and Visual Studio 2022. I get an error at the end of configuration saying that project files might be invalid. What should I check?

I expected to not get this error. Previously that I downloaded the source code (OpenCV) from github I didn't get this error, but later I encountered other problems when trying to work wih mexopencv in MatLab.